# Enforce other developers to have a validation class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, abstract-class, fluentvalidation

I have been building an API with fluent validation. I am working on the initial structure of the project. When I add more developers to the project, I need to enforce them to implement a Fluent Validation class for each model class.

Currently the validation works when validation is present. But it is not throwing an error when there's no validation present. Is there any way I can achieve a compilation error when no validation class is present? Like having an abstract function on query handler class which checks for the validation.

```
 public abstract class CommandHanlder<TCommand> : IRequestHandler<TCommand, ICommandResult> where TCommand : IRequest<ICommandResult>
{
    protected IDbContext DbContext { get; }
    public TCommand Command { get; private set; }

    protected CommandHanlder(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<ICommandResult> Handle(TCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CheckValidation();

        Command = request;

        ICommandResult commandResult;
        commandResult = await Execute();

        return commandResult;
    }

    protected abstract Task<ICommandResult> Execute();

    protected  bool CheckValidation()
    {
        // Need to check whether validation present else should throw a compilation error
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're setting this up. Generally, you're going to be fairly limited from a base class, as it's only going to have visibility to itself, not the classes derived from it. You could add an abstract property or method, but that only ensures that it's "implemented", not that it's implemented correctly. For example, let's say you want to force developers to implement `CheckValidation` by making it abstract. The following in a derived class would satisfy:

```
protected override bool CheckValidation() => true;
```

Which obviously doesn't actually solve anything.

Ultimately, if there's some validation class that you're providing via composition, it would be best to inject it into the base class:

```
public abstract class CommandHanlder<TCommand> : IRequestHandler<TCommand, ICommandResult>
    where TCommand : IRequest<ICommandResult>
{
    protected readonly IValidationClass _validationClass;

    protected CommandHandler(IValidationClass validationClass)
    {
        _validationClass = validationClass ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validationClass));
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, derived classes would need to provide a similar constructor:

```
protected MyDerivedCommandHandler(MyValidationClass validationClass)
    : base(validationClass)
```

That would then ensure that if some implementation of `IValidationClass` isn't passed in, that an exception will be raised.

Short of that, and perhaps better than that, is simple code review. There should be a build and release pipeline. Merges into master / your release branch should be done via pull requests, and those pull requests should require one or more reviewers. If someone adds a class like this without "validation", then, you can reject the pull requests, sending it back to the developer to fix.